How to do an Imagemagick barrel distort and maintain full photo data without autocrop?
I am applying barrel distortion to an image in imagemagick. The desired resulting image would look something like this:

As you can see, the photo is no longer a square, and the voids are filled with black. I cannot figure out how to do this in imagemagick. All my distorts are always auto cropped to a square.
magick in.jpg -virtual-pixel Black -distort Barrel "0 0 -0.3" out.png

I realize I can manually add pixels to the image, but I really want it to just auto grow to the resulting size of the distort. I have tried various things I have found online, to no avail.

You could try +distort rather than -distort. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#distort_bestfit.  Or you could use the viewport to make your image larger.   See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#distort_viewport

Post your input image so your command can be tested.

The answer seems to be using the 4th (D) parameter to specify the zoom out.
The formula is defaultD = 1-(A + B + C). Then increase defaultD slightly to zoom out.

Your answer would be considerably more useful to future readers if you added your input image, your output image and the command you used.
